# Show that if p is an odd prime, with p $\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ then $(\mathbb{Z}^*_{p})^4$ = $(\mathbb{Z}^*_{p})^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Show that if p is an odd prime, with p $\equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then $(\mathbb{Z}^*_{p})^4$ = $(\mathbb{Z}^*_{p})^2$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, I believe I need to use the Chinese Remainder map somehow.

Comment: I deleted my first suggestion, because I realized that you don't need cyclicity of $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$. I don't think CRT helps you this time.

Comment: BTW, many users expect askers to discuss their thoughts, or show some partial work. Here it is not easy to show partial progress, but can you try and apply the hint in my answer to the case $p=7$, please? Then you may see what's going on (using that $a^6=1$ for all $a\in\Bbb{Z}_7^*$)!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Assume that $m\equiv a^2\not\equiv0$. We were given that $p-1=4\ell+2$. So by Little Fermat
$$
m\equiv a^2\equiv a^2a^{p-1}\equiv a^{4(\ell+1)}.
$$